# 3 DIV side by side wont align correctly

Tags: html, css, button, alignment

I'm sure this is a facepalm moment for me, but a need some fresh eyes to have a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong... because I can't spot it!

That last button on the right needs to be in line with the other two, please help.

```css
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #333;
}

p {
 line-height: 1.65em;
 margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 margin: 0 0 1em 0;
 font-weight: normal;
}

/* BUTTON CONTAINER */

#buttoncointainer {
 width: 100%;
}

.buttontext {
 font-size: 175%;
 font: #fff;
}

/* LEFT BUTTON */

#arrowleft {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
 height: 40px;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 border: 1px solid #005698;
 margin-right: 3px;
 position: relative;
}

#arrowleft:hover {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
 height: 40px;
 background: #ECECEC;
 
}

.leftarrow {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 display: table-cell; 
 vertical-align: middle; 
 text-align: center; 
 height: 40px;
}

.leftarrow a:hover {
 color: #006ec3;
}

.leftarrow a {
 text-decoration:none;
 color: #fff;
}

/* SHARE BUTTON */

#sharebutton { 

    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
 background: #005698;
 height: 40px;
 border: 1px solid #005698;
}
#sharebutton:hover { 

    width: 40%;
 text-align: center;
 background: #006ec3;
 height: 40px;
}

.fb-share-text {
    color: #fff;
 text-align: center; 
}

.sbutton {
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.sbutton a {
 text-decoration:none;
 display:block
}

.sbutton a:hover {
 text-decoration:none;
 display:block;
 color: #006ec3;
}

/* RIGHT BUTTON */

#arrowright {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
 height: 40px;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 border: 1px solid #005698;
 margin-left: 3px;
 position: relative;
}

#arrowright:hover {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
 height: 40px;
 background: #ECECEC;
}

.rightarrow {
 float: right;
 width: 100%;
 display: table-cell; 
 vertical-align: middle; 
 text-align: center; 
 height: 40px;
}

.rightarrow a:hover {
 color: #006ec3;
}

.rightarrow a {
 text-decoration:none;
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttoncointainer">

 <div id="arrowleft">
  <div class="leftarrow">
   <p class="buttontext">
                ◄
            </p>
  </div>
 </div>
 
  <div id="sharebutton">
   <div class="sbutton">
    <p class="buttontext">
        Share
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
 
    <div id="arrowright">
  <div class="rightarrow">
      <p class="buttontext">
                ►
            </p>
  </div>
 </div>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order of your html for your code to take hold...

The `float:right;` element should be before the center aligned element.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
}
p {
  line-height: 1.65em;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}
/* BUTTON CONTAINER */

#buttoncointainer {
  width: 100%;
}
.buttontext {
  font-size: 175%;
  font: #fff;
}
/* LEFT BUTTON */

#arrowleft {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #005698;
  margin-right: 3px;
  position: relative;
}
#arrowleft:hover {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #ECECEC;
}
.leftarrow {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
}
.leftarrow a:hover {
  color: #006ec3;
}
.leftarrow a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
/* SHARE BUTTON */

#sharebutton {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: #005698;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #005698;
}
#sharebutton:hover {
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #006ec3;
  height: 40px;
}
.fb-share-text {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.sbutton {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.sbutton a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block
}
.sbutton a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: #006ec3;
}
/* RIGHT BUTTON */

#arrowright {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #005698;
  margin-left: 3px;
  position: relative;
}
#arrowright:hover {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #ECECEC;
}
.rightarrow {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
}
.rightarrow a:hover {
  color: #006ec3;
}
.rightarrow a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttoncointainer">

  <div id="arrowleft">
    <div class="leftarrow">
      <p class="buttontext">
        ◄
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="arrowright">
    <div class="rightarrow">
      <p class="buttontext">
        ►
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="sharebutton">
    <div class="sbutton">
      <p class="buttontext">
        Share
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made you a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/vmb0sfag/3/

Use float left on your main elements:

```css
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #333;
}

p {
 line-height: 1.65em;
 margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 margin: 0 0 1em 0;
 font-weight: normal;
}

/* BUTTON CONTAINER */

#buttoncointainer {
 width: 100%;
}

.buttontext {
 font-size: 175%;
 font: #fff;
}

/* LEFT BUTTON */

#arrowleft {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
 height: 40px;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 border: 1px solid #005698;
 margin-right: 3px;
 position: relative;
    float: left;
}

#arrowleft:hover {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
 height: 40px;
 background: #ECECEC;
 
}

.leftarrow {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 display: table-cell; 
 vertical-align: middle; 
 text-align: center; 
 height: 40px;
    float: left;
}

.leftarrow a:hover {
 color: #006ec3;
}

.leftarrow a {
 text-decoration:none;
 color: #fff;
}

/* SHARE BUTTON */

#sharebutton { 
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
 background: #005698;
 height: 40px;
 border: 1px solid #005698;
}
#sharebutton:hover { 

    width: 40%;
 text-align: center;
 background: #006ec3;
 height: 40px;
}

.fb-share-text {
    color: #fff;
 text-align: center; 
}

.sbutton {
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.sbutton a {
 text-decoration:none;
 display:block
}

.sbutton a:hover {
 text-decoration:none;
 display:block;
 color: #006ec3;
}

/* RIGHT BUTTON */

#arrowright {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
 height: 40px;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 border: 1px solid #005698;
 margin-left: 3px;
 position: relative;
    float: left;
}

#arrowright:hover {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
 height: 40px;
 background: #ECECEC;
}

.rightarrow {
 float: right;
 width: 100%;
 display: table-cell; 
 vertical-align: middle; 
 text-align: center; 
 height: 40px;
}

.rightarrow a:hover {
 color: #006ec3;
}

.rightarrow a {
 text-decoration:none;
 color: #fff;
}
```